# How do I replace a keyword with links but only words outside <a>

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this text 
"hi my name is google check out my page" 
i want replace google with link eg google.com
i use this php function `str_replace`

code:

```
<?php
$text = 'hi my name is google check out my page';
echo str_replace ('google' , '<a href="http://google.com/">google</a>' , $text);

?>
```

this will output

```
hi my name is <a href="http://google.com/">google</a>check out my page
```

the problem if i run this code again 
the output will repeat the replace

```
hi my name is <a href="http://<a href="http://google.com/">google</a>.com/"><a href="http://google.com/">google</a></a>check out my page
```

**I want only replace text not in `<a> or <img>`**
any help please

Comment: Why is this code being ran a second time?

Comment: this code not the real code in my script this code for explanation what i want, the real code will replace some words in database and will run alot of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change from str_replace to preg_replace. That way to can run a regex to make sure the value before google is not / or >.

```
preg_replace('/(?<![\/>])google/i', '<a href="http://google.com/">google</a>', $text);
```

Comment: thank you is's worked , but can we only replace the word only eg if i have word like "egoogle" and i will replaced google and leave "e" i do not want replace the word only if the word Exact the replace thanks

Comment: yes it's worked but i want it Replace the word exactly, eg if the text is "my name is egoogle" i want to ignore this because egoogle not google and will cut google and replace with link and leave "e"

Comment: What about using this: (\s(google)\s)|(^(google)\s)|(\s(google)$) This will onyl match google that have space in front and back or is in the end og start of the subject.

Comment: it's worked '/(?<![\/>])(\s(google)\s)|(^(google)\s)|(\s(google)$)/i' thank you but is this safe for none english chars? it's utf8 encoded text ? thanks

Comment: It should not be a problem with utf8 chars.